# Error in my dataset

Tags: python, pandas

Currently, I am getting this error in my code

```
'ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')'
```

when I want to run this code

```
import pandas as pd

train=pd.read_csv('C:\Users\ABDILLAH\Desktop\datasets\Rails\RailsDataset.csv')

features_col=['Num_comments', 'Num_Commits','Changed_files']

X=train.loc[:,features_col]
y=train.classes

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

logreg=LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(X,y)`
```

So if you need a sample of my dataset to check what is realy happened please let me know

Comment: As the error message you nite references on your input, the input dataset seems not to match the expected format (float64). Either double check your dataset on your own or provide also the dataset so that it can be reviewed..

Comment: Check whether u got any missing values in the dataset.. If you can,  please provide the link for the dataset so that we can see what the issue really is

Comment: How can I send the link to you? It's a local database. Is there any way to attach files? So that I can attach the file or give me an email address Please

Comment: Hi, here is the link to my data https://github.com/abdimomo/training-project/blob/master/RailsDataset_bis.csv. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've loaded the sample set and the code below ran in my computer:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

train = pd.read_csv('RailsDataset_bis.csv')
features_col = ['Num_Comments', 'Num_Commits', 'Changed_files']

X = train[features_col].dropna()
y = train['class'].dropna()

logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(X, y)
```

I've have corrected issues such as:

1. There is no `Num_comments` column, there only is a `Num_Comments`
   column as `pandas` is case-sensitive. This line
   `X=train.loc[:,features_col]` didn't give you an error, but
   generated a column full of `NaN`. Selecting columns like this `X = train[features_col]`will throw an error in case the column name doesn't exist.
2. There is no `train.classes` as the column name is `class` and not `classes`.
3. There was a line full of `NaN` on the bottom of the set that needed to be
   removed with `dropna()`.